# Writing array fill with a macro

Tags: scala, macros

I am trying to write a function which fills an array with a given value using scala macros. For instance a call to:

```
val ary = Array( 0, 1, 2 )
fill3( ary, 50+25 )
```

should be expanded to:

```
val ary = Array(0, 1, 2 )
{
  val $value = 50+25
  ary(0) = $value
  ary(1) = $value
  ary(2) = $value       
}
```

Here is my first attempt:

```
def fill3( ary: Array[Int], x: Int ) = macro fill_impl3

def fill_impl3( c: Context )
( ary: c.Expr[Array[Int]], x: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._        
  def const(x:Int) = Literal(Constant(x))

  //Precompute x
  val valName = newTermName("$value")
  val valdef = ValDef( Modifiers(), valName, TypeTree(typeOf[Int]), x.tree )

  val updates = List.tabulate( 3 ){
  i => Apply( Select( ary.tree, "update"), List( const(i), ??? ) )
  }

  val insts = valdef :: updates
  c.Expr[Unit](Block(insts:_*))
}
```

But here I'm stuck for two reasons:

1. I don't know hot to get the precomputed value (`$value`)
2. I need several of these function for Arrays of size 3, 4, 6, 9 and 27. Is there a way to dry the definitions, or should I write `fill3`, `fill4`, `fill6`, etc.

Is there the right way to proceed ? How can I solve my two problems ?

**EDIT:** I realized my initial question was stupid because the size must be known at compile time...

Comment: Is the size of the array known at compile time?

Comment: I just updated the question to clarify this point. I simplified the problem with a fixed size.

Comment: What would be the benefit of using a macro here?

Comment: And is the value known at compile time or can it be some arbitrary expression?

Comment: @kimstebel 1. Learning macros. 2. I am rewriting a numerical intensive code that uses lots of computations on small size arrays (size known at compile time). I would like to see if I can gain some speed-up by unrolling all loops to avoid incrementing counters and the bound check. I plan to write vector operations this way.

Comment: @KimStebel: the value can be an arbitrary expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def fill(size:Int, ary: Array[Int], x: Int ) = macro fill_impl

def fill_impl( c: Context )
(size:c.Expr[Int], ary: c.Expr[Array[Int]], x: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._        
  def const(x:Int) = Literal(Constant(x))

  val Literal(Constant(arySize:Int)) = size.tree

  //Precompute x
  val valName = newTermName("$value")
  val valdef = ValDef( Modifiers(), valName, TypeTree(typeOf[Int]), x.tree )

  val updates = List.tabulate( arySize ){
  i => Apply( Select( ary.tree, "update"), List( const(i), Ident(valName) ) )
  }

  val insts = valdef :: updates
  c.Expr[Unit](Block(insts:_*))
}
```

Comment: that is strange, I am using M6 too. Is your project available somewhere?

Comment: how do you compile that without splitting it into subprojects?

Comment: I will split it in subprojects, but currently I stupidly comment the main method and when then macro compiles I uncomment it...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to figure it out by using `reify` along with printing the raw tree of its result:

```
def fill_impl3( c: Context )
( ary: c.Expr[Array[Int]], x: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._
  val r = reify {
     val $value = x.splice
     val $arr  = ary.splice
     $arr(0)   = $value
     $arr(1)   = $value
     $arr(2)   = $value
  }
  println( showRaw( r.tree ))
  r
}
```

Which gives something like

```
val vt = newTermName("$value")
val at = newTermName("$arr")
val ut = newTermName("update")
Block(List(
  ValDef(Modifiers(), vt, TypeTree(), ...),
  ValDef(Modifiers(), at, TypeTree(), ...),
  Apply(Select(Ident(at), ut), List(Literal(Constant(0)), Ident(vt))),
  Apply(Select(Ident(at), ut), List(Literal(Constant(1)), Ident(vt)))),
  Apply(Select(Ident(at), ut), List(Literal(Constant(2)), Ident(vt)))
)
```

Comment: Do not use `$` on identifiers! They are reserved for the compiler, and reifying already protects you from identifier clash.